# Why can't the future package find my function?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, parallel.foreach

I asked a similar question earlier today but @MrFlick found a problem with my reproducible example. Now I have another reproducible example, and I think this one works.

The problem is that the future package cannot see one of my functions. I also tried with foreach and it has the same problem: it cannot see the same function. So here is the code:

```
library("future")
library("tidyverse")
library("rlist")

aspect.major.names <- c("Conjunction", "Opposition", "Trine", "Square", "Sextile")

aspect_strength <- function(angle, center=0, orb=8) {
  abs_angle <- abs(angle)
  calculated_angle <- if (abs_angle >= center - orb && abs_angle <= center + orb) {
    abs_angle
  } else {
    abs_angle_360 <- 360 - abs_angle
    if (abs_angle_360 >= center - orb && abs_angle_360 <= center + orb) {
      abs_angle_360} else {-1}
  }
  if (calculated_angle < 0) {return(0)}

  1 - abs(calculated_angle - center)/orb
}

conjunction_func <- function(x) aspect_strength(x, 0, conjunction_orb)
conjunction_strength <- function(x) sapply(x, conjunction_func)
sextile_func <- function(x) aspect_strength(x, 60, sextile_orb)
sextile_strength <- function(x) sapply(x, sextile_func)
square_func <- function(x) aspect_strength(x, 90, square_orb)
square_strength <- function(x) sapply(x, square_func)
trine_func <- function(x) aspect_strength(x, 120, trine_orb)
trine_strength <- function(x) sapply(x, trine_func)
opposition_func <- function(x) aspect_strength(x, 180, opposition_orb)
opposition_strength <- function(x) sapply(x, opposition_func)

strength_funcs <- c(conjunction_strength, opposition_strength,
                    trine_strength, square_strength, sextile_strength)
names(strength_funcs) <- aspect.major.names

smoa <- c(15.402917, 29.143750, 42.892500, 56.533333, 69.970417, 83.142083, 96.012500, 108.580000, 120.861667, 132.891667)
smea <- c(339.32542, 339.63667, 339.96375, 340.30792, 340.67208, 341.04917, 341.44333, 341.85042, 342.26750, 342.70167)
df_angles <- data.frame(Sun_Moon_Angle = smoa, Sun_Mercury_Angle = smea)

orb <- 8
conjunction_orb <- sextile_orb <- square_orb <- trine_orb <- opposition_orb <- orb

csma <- function(asp) {

  # This is needed otherwise there is an error
  # conjunction_func
  # opposition_func
  # trine_func
  # square_func
  # sextile_func

  df_angles %>%
    apply(2, strength_funcs[[asp]]) %>%
    as.data.frame() -> df_strength
  df_strength
}

plan(sequential)
plan(multisession, workers=6)
futs <- lapply(aspect.major.names, function(x) future({ csma(x) }))
lapply(futs, value) %>% list.cbind() -> dfsmas
```

When I run this code I get the following message:

```
lapply(futs, value) %>% list.cbind() -> dfsmas
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'conjunction_func' not found
```

The first lapply executes with no problems. It is in the second one, which calls the value function, that the error occurs.

What is odd (at least to me) is that if one uncomments these lines within the csma function the code works and there is no error.

```
  # conjunction_func
  # opposition_func
  # trine_func
  # square_func
  # sextile_func
```

Uncommented, these lines seem to remind future that these functions exist.

Comment: `df_angles` does not seem to be defined here. Please define all variables to make this example reproducible.

Comment: No data object.: `df_angles`. Debugging requires them. Not a [MCVE]

Comment: @MrFlick, sorry. I now realize I had to run this code in a clean session. Learning new things. I added some code and cut and pasted it in a new RGui session outside of RStudio to make sure no variables or functions were missing. The code fails as described before: cannot find conjunction_func. If some lines of code inside function csma, including one that consists of 'conjunction_func' (without the quotes), are uncommented the code runs fine. The error message is also simpler in the RGui session as compared to the one in RStudio. That was changed too in this new iteration.

Comment: Suggestion: Start by taking **future** out of the equation, i.e. get it working without attaching the **future** package and using `future()`. Only when that works, try it with futures.

Comment: @HenrikB - It works without futures. It even works with futures if one does the hack of copying the names (just the names) of conjunction_func and the other similar functions inside the body of the csma function. I am using it on a daily basis and it works fine. It is just a bit weird that it works if and only if those names are sitting there doing nothing.

Comment: Sorry for thread necromancy, but I just had the same problem and @Soldalma 's hack worked for me. Briefly: When in a future::future() I call a function X that calls a function Y, I got the error 'Error in X() : could not find function "Y"'. Just putting `Y` [NOT `Y()`] up top in my expression passed to future::future() solved the issue.